# Writing a string backwards

Tags: python, string, recursion

This is my simple code.

```
def reverseString(aStr):
    newStr = ''
    if len(aStr) == 0:
        return newStr
    else:
        newStr = newStr + aStr[len(aStr)-1]
        return reverseString(aStr[:len(aStr)-1])
```

For `'alina'` (if I  insert `print newStr` before `return reverseString...`), the output is: `newStr='a'`, `newStr='n'`, `newStr='i'`, `newStr='l'`, `newStr='a'`, `newStr=''`. I don't get it. Why does it behave like this?

Comment: `aStr[len(aStr)-1]` is `aStr[-1]`

Comment: How about `aStr[::-1]`?

Comment: use extended slicing: `aStr[::-1]` this will fix it right and good for you.

Comment: or you can use the `reversed()` function `newStr = ''.join(reversed(aStr))` (same thing as extended slicing, but more elegant)

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532902/python-reversing-a-string-using-recursion?rq=1) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
def reverseString(aStr, newStr = ''):
    if len(aStr) == 0:
        return newStr
    else:
        newStr = newStr + aStr[-1]  #-1 returns the last element from the string
        return reverseString(aStr[:-1], newStr) #slice the string up to second last char
print reverseString("foobar")     
#raboof
```

The problem with your code is that `newStr` is getting re-assigned at each recursive loop to an empty string(`''`), you must pass the `newStr` value in every recursive call.

```
def reverseString(aStr, newStr= ''): #define a default value for newStr

    if len(aStr) == 0:
        return newStr
    else:
        newStr = newStr + aStr[len(aStr)-1]  #better use aStr[-1]
        return reverseString(aStr[:len(aStr)-1], newStr) #pass the new value of newStr

print reverseString("foobar")# No value is passed for newStr. So, default is used .
```

Comment: why not choose `newStr = ''` as default?

Comment: @Elazar good point, for a moment I forgot strings are immutable in python.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your function has not worked is because you forgot to return `newStr` at the end. And every time you call your function, `newStr` will just get reset back to `''`.

There's an easier way to do what you are doing. Use [slicing](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
def reverseString(s):
    return s[::-1]
```

Examples:

```
>>> reverseString('alina')
'anila'

>>> reverseString('racecar')
'racecar' # See what I did there ;)
```

Comment: the question is "Why does it behave like this?". this is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

You are returning the result of the recursive call, without keeping the information from previous calls. You have this line:

```
newStr = newStr + aStr[len(aStr)-1]
```

but newStr is then discarded.

Possible solution:

```
def reverseString(aStr):
    if len(aStr) == 0:
        return ''
    else:
        return aStr[-1] + reverseString(aStr[:-1])
```

or simply

```
def reverseString(s):
    return s[-1]+reverseString(s[:-1]) if s else ''
```

Note that both these solutions are elegant, but are "normal" recursion, and therefore suboptimal; for a tail-recursive solution (which potentially can be optimized into a loop) see @Ashwini Chaudhary's answer.

Comment: Thank you! Problem was I never returned newStr.

Comment: -1 to enforce use of recursion in a programming language that is not tailored to do this. It is Python, not Haskell.

Comment: @doukremt thanks. This enforcement is the OP's (what is called "CS excercise"), not mine, but your point is clear.

Answer (score -1):

Just sayin', there's an easier way to do this, which avoids recursion and the problems that it entails :

```
>>> ''.join(reversed("abcd"))
'dcba'
```

Comment: just saying, this is the 6th time this solution is being suggested here. This is a comment, not an answer, and one that has been suggested already.

Comment: Yes, but I am a vet trying to learn programming so I have to understand things first... :)

Comment: @Elazar: I don't see this method mentioned in this page, except in my answer.

Comment: See zmo's and Schorsch's comments.

Comment: @doukremt There are two deleted answers that you cannot see which suggested that already; one of the users who wrote those answers added a comment to the question.